# Can iPad pro replace MacBook for music production?

Tags: daw, production

I watched a video on YouTube titled 2018 iPad Pro - the Future of Music

In the video, a professional music producer only uses his iPad to make all his music.

So I'm wondering if the new 2018 iPad pro can do everything that the MacOS DAWs can do. Are there any important features of the MacOS DAWs that the iPad pro cannot replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it's not the feature set of any portable solution but the real-estate.

I grew up on Pro24 on an Atari, with a 12" screen. This was already a vast improvement on previous hardware sequencers, with nothing more than a tiny LCD display to work on.

It's the equivalent of trying to decorate the hallway through the letterbox.
 <sup>That references an old joke I'm not sure is appropriate for in here ;-)</sup>

Since the 90's I've had two screens - as large as could be obtained at the time, & currently work on two 1440p 27" displays.

That means I've room for my main arrange page on one & my mixer on the other, with enough room left to have half a dozen plugins open at the same time, without everything being hidden behind everything else.

So, sure, you can work on an iPad Pro... but only if you're willing to give up all that screen space.

Answer (score 1):

This bit of puffery for Apple, I imagine?

He's using maybe 1% of a DAW's capability to make 'beats'.  There's equipment being used apart from the iPad.  That keyboard, for a start.  (And who in his right mind connects a keyboard by Bluetooth when it's sitting right next to the DAW?).

Yes, everything gets smaller and more powerful.  But not THAT much.  Yet.

Comment: for me, the dealbreaker is the lack of a headphone jack on the new iPad pro. Maybe Apple will make it easier for musicians in the future. I do really want the tactile interaction with the UI which my MacBook can't provide. Touching is a lot more intuitive than dragging everything with my mouse.

Comment: Windows seems rather ahead of Mac in enabling touch-screen control on their 'real' computers.

Comment: True, but Jobs was adamant that a laptop touchscreen is not ergonomic and he was (in my humble opinion) correct. That's one of the very few things that Cook has kept alive in the current Apple landscape, even if just by chance.